# Stop option disabled in avd manager

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, emulation, avd-manager

Stop is greyed out in emulator for my virtual device.
I want to use this in order to fix an error that says

> waiting for target to come online

before starting emulator

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

1. Close the Android Studio
2. Delete the .idea folder from the project
3. Relaunch the Android studio and reopen your project

If this doesn’t help then please try to open the Android Studio in Admin mode. This issue could happened if Android Studio is launched in non-Administrator mode and it then failed to  identify the android sdk installation on your machine

**Solution:** Relaunch Android Studio in administrator mode and configuring the android sdk: *sudo /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio* [For Mac, If it has installed in default Applications directory]